# React JS App becomes blank white screen when deployed with AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, aws-amplify

I have a React JS app that works on local host, but when I deploy to AWS amplify displays as a blank white screen with no body. The browser tab shows the correct title and icon.

The page returns status code 403 and I believe there is a CORS issue? I have been unable to correct this in my code or on the Amplify console. Can someone point me towards what is causing my problem? I have successfully deployed a different React app with Amplify.

[image: Body missing from dev console]

[image: Error reading]

Comment: In React, blank white screens are usually associated with an error. Open the browser console and edit your question with the one you see. Also, it'd be strange if a 403 error (Unauthorized) meant CORS issues.

Comment: I included a photo of the error with my post. Here's a link to my site: https://main.d19qyiuqppvhny.amplifyapp.com/

Comment: What I mean is the browser console. Sure enough, [I see an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm6Fb.png) Looks like the files you're requesting have restricted access. Are you sure you configured your public files correctly?

Comment: No, I've been all over google and stack overflow but I don't know how to configure it. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hopefully this will help: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/host-static-website/

Comment: Thanks, but I've already used that guide. That's how I set up my project with Amplify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242582/discussion-between-zdubya-and-code).

Comment: @chip I'm sorry?

Comment: @code you had option to be convivial, but you chose violence.

Comment: @chip it appears your previous comment was deleted. Without the context, I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I needed to change the homepage url in the package.json to match my Amplify URL. To do this add, or modify, the following line in your package.json:

```
 "homepage": "{Amplify-URL}/#/"
```

The Amplify URL can be found in the Amplify console under App settings -> Domain Management -> URL.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Bro you really saved my day I saw your comment but I ignored it first and searched all over the google for the whole day nothing helped but you saved my day. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In the build settings i.e. the amplify.yml file, you need to specify under artifacts the base directory which webpack or the build tool being used will generate.In my case this is the dist directory, because due to running yarn build command.

```
 artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist
```